# How to get whole data from Solr

Tags: java, search, solr, solrj

I have to write some logic in Java which should retrieve all the index data from Solr.

As of now I am doing it like this

```
        String confSolrUrl = "http://localhost/solr/master/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true"
        LOG.info(confSolrUrl);
        url = new URL(confSolrUrl);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;

        //save to this filename
        String fileName = "/qwertyuiop.html";
        File file = new File(fileName);

        if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            bw.write(inputLine);
        }

        bw.close();
        br.close();

        System.out.println("Done");
```

In my file I will get the whole `HTML` file that I can parse and extract my `JSON`.

Is there any better way to do it? 
Instead of get the resource from the url and parse it?

Comment: what do you mean index? solr index consists of multiple binary files

Comment: I mean the file that you retrieve when you go to the dashboard under Query and search for all. You get a JSON result of all your index

Comment: Like the code here? Search using SolrJ - http://www.solrtutorial.com/solrj-tutorial.html

Comment: what I mean is how can I get all my index file from solr in a JSON format ? It is may possible via an empty search ?

Comment: okay, you want to extract whole index in JSON format, that's the question

Comment: yes I need te whole index in JSON format, is it possible ?  @Mysterion

Comment: @OEH please edit your question to reflect what you really need and provide the code you wrote as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wrote an application to do this, take a look at github: https://github.com/freedev/solr-import-export-json

If you want read all data from a solr collection the first problem you're facing is the pagination, in this case we are talking of deep paging.

A direct http request like you did will return a relative short amount of documents. And you can even have millions or billions of documents in a solr collection.
So you should use the correct API, i.e. [Solrj](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ).

In my project I just did it.

I would also suggest this reading: 
https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/12/12/coming-soon-to-solr-efficient-cursor-based-iteration-of-large-result-sets/

Comment: awesome and handy tool